When children have active class, the text filter will be bold
When tag link is clicked, .active will be added to that specific tag. I want when there's .active present on the tag, the p will turn blue (.active is added to the p).
I managed to turn the p to blue. However, I'm having trouble removing the blue color and .active when the tag link is not active.


$('.tag').click(function() {
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
  if (clicks) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  }
  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});


$('.tag').click(function() {
  var numActive = $('.active').length
  if (numActive > 0) {
    $(this).closest('.wrap').find('.filter').addClass('active');
  } else {
    $(this).closest('.wrap').find('.filter').removeClass('active');
  }
})
.tag.active {
  color: red;
}

.filter.active {
  color: blue;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <p class="filter">filter</p>
  <div class="tag-wrap">
    <a class="tag">tag 1</a>
    <a class="tag">tag 2</a>  
    <a class="tag">tag 3</a>
  </div>
</div>




You can try this also
$('.tag').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      $('.filter').toggleClass('active', $('.tag').hasClass('active'));
 });


Thank you @naushad but the toggle doesn't work if I click to highlight every second link. It will go back to black when I press the second tag link, and highlighted again when click the 3rd tag link.

You can combine the logic into one click handler and simplify it using toggleClass:


$('.tag').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  updateFilter();
});

function updateFilter() {
  $('.filter').toggleClass('active', $('.tag.active').length > 0);
}
.tag.active {
  color: red;
}

.filter.active {
  color: blue;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <p class="filter">filter</p>
  <div class="tag-wrap">
    <a class="tag">tag 1</a>
    <a class="tag">tag 2</a>  
    <a class="tag">tag 3</a>
  </div>
</div>




also change this css to make filter text bold: .filter.active {color: blue; font-weight:bold;}

Thank you @Invulner but the toggle doesn't work if I click to highlight every second link. It will go back to black when I press the second tag link, and highlighted again when click the 3rd tag link.

@feliel93 I didn't understand. Run my code snippet - click on any link to keep the filter active as long as any link has the active class. The active class from the filter will be removed only when no link has the active class.
